# Configurable Product Turning into Simple Products Mass Import CSV Magento2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, csv, simple-product, file-upload

Hello StackExchange community!

I am having a serious issue with my Magento CSV **mass product import** to **Magento2**.

I have about 1800 SKUs to upload and am **testing a configurable product** and their corresponding simple products to start.

My issue is, is that my configurable product, says configurable within the CSV column, but is being **transposed as a simple product** upon upload completion.

This obviously, is **not allowing me to view the product in different sizes**, as it would be if the configurable product loaded.

Magento 2 will also *not* allow me to upload this "configurable" product without a price, which I find strange.

Can someone please help with this situation? I can elaborate further if required.

Comment: All,I have figured out the issues should it be relevant for any who stumble upon this question: Attribute sets were not set correctly to match the grouped product attributes, so therefore, Magento was not offering the attribute sets that the configurable product was set to point to, hence, rendering the different products (sizes) invisible from the overall website.

Comment: Further more make sure that the following columns align within the CSV: attribute_set_code HAS to align with the product attributes that are set to it WITHIN THE CSV AND MAGENTO